# How to convert array with objects to one object like Laravel Request object

Tags: arrays, laravel, object, laravel-5

I have an array like this:

```
[{FirstName: "fff"},
{LastName: null},
{Nationality: null},
{Year: null},
{Month: null},
{Day: null}]
```

I need to convert it to one object like this: (with Laravel or with JS)

```
{FirstName: "fff",
LastName: null,
Nationality: null,
Year: null,
Month: null,
Day: null}
```

I need one object exactly like Laravel request object. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the array nest with objects is variable `$a`

```php
function multipleObjsToObj($a) {
    $b = json_encode($a, true);     // encode to string
    $array = json_decode($b, true); // decode to all array

    // use collection flatMap or mapWithKeys to flatten with keys:
    // $flatten_array = collect($array)->mapWithKeys(function($item){return $item;})->toArray();
    $flatten_array = collect($array)->flatMap(function($item){return $item;})->all();

    return (object) $flatten_array; // here become to object.
}
```